# Boot-Repair - No repair recommended

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I see a lot of questions on this topic, perhaps if I was more experienced I would be able to see a solution to my problem. I am running a dual boot with Windows XP + Ubuntu 14.04 for about 6 months with no problems, but now on start-up:

```
error: no such partition
followed by "Entering rescue mode" and the grub prompt
grub rescue>
```

I ran BootRepair twice:

1. From a liveUSB boot of Ubuntu I installed and ran Boot Repair
2. From a downloaded 'disk copy' on USB.

Both produced the same results, I did not get the "recommended Repair" button only the information found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10676603/).

Now I am stuck and would welcome some help, I could do a full reinstall of Ubuntu but I am concerned that I will then lose Windows XP forever as I have no media from which to reinstall it.

Comment: While partition table shows partitions, none of them were able to be parsed to know what is in them. Normally one partition needing fsck if ext4 or chkdsk if NTFS may happen on an abnormal shutdown, having all partitions seems very strange. I do see sda3 shown a gpt and gpt & MBR are not normally mixed. I might run fixparts to see if the partition table is valid. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

Comment: @oldfred this is my exact case. Messed up with my partitions after abnormal shutdown, now they arent visible anywhere, although they exist!

Comment: @testing_22 Please post your own question. And any partition table info like fdisk or gdisk outputs or Boot-Repair's report link in your question.

Comment: Theres no partition table nor boot repair output, it won't recognize the SSD at all. However, it does recognize when I boot to Windows on the same SSD!! (But cant Access its files since they're ext)

Answer (score 0):

it seems your boot loader is corrupted. I suggest re-installing the grub boot loader from a live usb/cd on your system. The best choice is to fix this from a live usb so as to not corrupt your windows system. 
[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is a link to show you how to re-install the boot loader.